# using location.href with jquery tab

Tags: jquery, redirect

I need to redirect to a page using javascript/jquery.

I have a page with jquery tabs and in `Settings` tab i have a link to load some preferences of the user in thickbox and after update i need to reload the main page.

I am using `location.href = "/User/Update/" + $('#UserId').val() + "#Settings";` to redirect/reload the page, but the page is not reloading. The problem seems to be when i redirect to the same page from where i load the thickbox.

How can i redirect using location.href for jquery tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the location to another location on the same page. The browser doesn't reload because it assumes nothing has changed.

Try:

```
location.reload(true)
```